# CSS applied to aspx page working in firefox, but not IE. Only the style of 1 button doesn't work. Any ideas?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, vb.net

this is the CSS for the button....

```
.button:last-of-type,.button:visited, .button:hover, .button:active, .button:active {
    background: #7C8C99;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

the html in IE...

```
 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1" class="button" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you haven't actually added any style for .button

Comment: which ie version did you test the page with? because `last-of-type` only works on IE9 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The `last-of-type` is CSS3 property is not supported in IE<9.

Try the following  CSS:

```
.button{
    background: #7C8C99;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```